# syntax error for typedef

Tags: c++, syntax-error, typedef

I am faced with the following syntax error whle building a 3rd party lib

```
error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'
```

for the following typedef declaration

```
typedef SO2Group<double> SO2 EIGEN_DEPRECATED;
```

The syntax is indeed not what I am familar with, however similar declartion have been found on multiple files of the project so I do not believe its a typo.

Is the above typedef declaration legal and how should I go about fixing the error?

thanks

Comment: We can't tell whether it is legal or not because we don't know what `SO2` or `EIGEN_DEPRECATED` are. Are they macros? What are their expansions?

Comment: If you invoke the compiler with preprocess only options (e.g. `gcc -E`) you should be able to see exactly what it's trying to parse after preprocessing.  I'd hazard that your SO2 is injecting a name, so the compiler thinks the typedef should be finished and should be followed by a `';'`, but instead `EIGEN_DEPRECATED` is replaced with `int` leading to the error.

Comment: EIGEN_DEPRECATED expends to `#define EIGEN_DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)`. while SO2 as far as I know is the name of the new type. I used cmake provided with the lib to generate a vs10 project for building, could the issue be caused by vs10?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to build the Sohpus library: a C++ implementation of Lie Groups using Eigen. I ran into the same problem and it seems to be an MSVC problem. I found this [fork of the Sophus library](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Sophus/commits/master). This should compile using MSVC.

Comment: here ran into the same problem; forked from(stevenlovegrove/Sophus/);MSVC compiling errors gone.thanks @tobyhijzen and stevenlovegrove.